# Should I show my bank statement when I am being fully sponsored by a family member?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-funds

I was refused a business visit visa to the UK recently because my sponsor's deposits did not match his salary. They also objected that I did not show my bank statements hence 'not shown proof of my financial circumstances in Pakistan'. What I wanted to know is when I reapply, do I really need to attach my statement, since it is only sufficient to support my daily expenses and my credit is equal to my debit? I am afraid they might object to it since I have known people who have gotten their visas rejected on the basis of insufficient funds in their bank account even when they were NOT their own sponsor.

Comment: what was exactly your main purpose for visiting uk, also what do u do in Pakistan and who was your sponsor in uk a businessman or salaried person?

Answer (score 1):

Your bank statements have two different purposes.

- They show that you can afford the daily expenses of travel in the UK.
- They show that you have a steady income where you come from. This means you **appear** less likely to overstay and to take illegal work.

Sponsorship takes care of the first bullet point. You still have to convince the visa officials that you plan to leave again. Bank statements may help with that.